# how to use connect with member function

Tags: qt, signals

I want to connect the `tabBarDoubleClicked` signal with a member function but the compiler keeps barking at me with:

```
/home/ron/src/kterminal/sessionstack.cpp:79:56: error: invalid use of non-static member function
         this, SessionStack::editTabLabel(session->id()));
                                                        ^
```

and I'm not sure how to fix it, my code looks like:

```
int SessionStack::addSession(Session::SessionType type)
{
    Session* session = new Session(type, this);
    connect(session, SIGNAL(titleChanged(int,QString)), this, SIGNAL(titleChanged(int,QString)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(terminalManuallyActivated(Terminal*)), this, SLOT(handleManualTerminalActivation(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(activityDetected(Terminal*)), m_window, SLOT(handleTerminalActivity(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(silenceDetected(Terminal*)), m_window, SLOT(handleTerminalSilence(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(destroyed(int)), this, SLOT(cleanup(int)));

    m_sessions.insert(session->id(), session);

    QString tab_label = QString("Shell (") + QString::number(session->id(), 16) + ")";
    addTab(session->widget(), tr(qPrintable(tab_label)));

    emit sessionAdded(session->id());

    raiseSession(session->id());

    connect(this, tabBarDoubleClicked,
        this, SessionStack::editTabLabel(session->id()));

    return session->id();   
}

void SessionStack::editTabLabel(int tabIndex)
{
```

How can I get `editTabLabel()` invoked when the tab is double clicked?

**EDIT1**

In my header I have the following declared:
class SessionStack : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", "org.kde.kterminal")

```
public:
    explicit SessionStack(QWidget* parent, QWidget* window);
    ~SessionStack();

private slots:
    void tabBarDoubleClicked(int index);
    void editTabLabel(int tabIndex);
```

};

Comment: Do you mean to call `editTabLabel` with `session->id()` as its argument? or should it be called with the `int` from `tabBarDoubleClicked` signal?

Comment: In the class `SessionStack`, have you declared the signal `tabBarDoubleClicked`? or do you mean to use the [`QTabWidget::tabBarDoubleClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabBarDoubleClicked) signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the error occurs because you just forgot to add SIGNAL and SLOT macros at

> connect(this, tabBarDoubleClicked, this, SessionStack::editTabLabel(session->id()));

- You can't pass session->id() while connecting, you can only pass the argument when you emit the signal.
- Please note that your code is not going to connect anyway in runtime since the signal misses an argument (int), so that it matches the editTabLabel slot. So you need to fix that as well.. should be

  ```
  connect(this, SINGAL(tabBarDoubleClicked(int), this, SLOT(editTabLabel(int)));
  ```
- if the signal "tabBarDoubleClicked" is builtin and you can't change it to add an argument then you might consider QSignalMapper http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html

Comment: You can't pass arguments to slots like that `SLOT(editTabLabel(session->id()))`.

Comment: right ! just fixed my answer .. thanks for your comment ..@Mike